# Why using asterisk when using size in C language?

Tags: c, pointers

So the question is originated from Leetcode:

> In a n * m two-dimensional array, each row is sorted in increasing order from left to right, and each column is sorted in increasing order from top to bottom. Please complete a function, input such a two-dimensional array and an integer, and determine whether the array contains the integer.

And my C solution is:

```
1 bool findNumberIn2DArray(int** matrix, int matrixSize, int* matrixColSize, int target){
2     //return matrixSize==5;
3     for(int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
4     {
5         for (int j = 0; j < *matrixColSize; j++)
6         {
7             int num = matrix[i][j];
8             if (num == target) {return true;}
9             if (num > target) {break;}
10        }
11    }
12    return false;
13}
```

In row 5, It has to be `*matrixColSize`. If I remove the asterisk, the memory will overflow. From my perspective, the `matrixColSize` is an INT. Why can't I use the INT directly but have to use a pointer?

Maybe I didn't make my question clear. I know it's a pointer, and I know a pointer is totally different from an INT. My question is, why is this question using a pointer here to define the `matrixColSize` but not just using and INT? From my perspective, an INT is enough here to represent the size.

Can anybody tell me why please?

Comment: If you remove the asterisk you should get an error message. If you do not see one then adjust your compiler settings

Comment: `matraxColSize` is a `int*` an address of an integer.  You have to dereference it with `*` to get the integer.

Comment: You say it's your code so you wrote `int* matrixColSize`. Do you know what a pointer is? Why did you make it a pointer instead of `int matrixColSize` like the `matrixSize` parameter?

Comment: "From my perspective, the matrixColSize is an INT". Why do you think that? `int` is an int. `int *` is not an int, it is a pointer to an int.

Comment: Eh, maybe I didn't make my question clear. I know it's a pointer, and I know a pointer is totally different from an INT. My question is, why using a pointer here to define the matrixColSize but not just using and INT? From my perspective, an INT is enough here to represent the size.

Comment: @happyjoo You are right.  There is no reason to use a pointer for matrixColSize unless it points to an array of all the sizes of all the columns.  Are you sure that matrixColSize is an int and not an array of integers?  I guess if it is an n * m matrix all the columns should be the same size so it should be an int, but if it isn't then there must be a reason.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yes yes, I guess it's the size array of the matrix column. An INT is enough for an n * m matrix. So maybe Leetcode just uses the pointer for its convenience. Maybe it's just the same code template.

Comment: @happyjoo  If it is an entire array of all the sizes of all the columns then for a m*n matrix all the sizes of all the columns are the same and it doesn't matter which column size you use so the zeroth one is fine.  If it is an array, then you could use `matrixColSize[i]` so that you are using the correct column size but if they are all the same the `*matrixColSize` and `matrixColSize[0]` work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you define as a function parameter `int* matrixColSize` if you delete `*` in 5. line, you basically say that increase j till address of `matrixColSize`.

And it is very large number because an address like 0x88644278. So thats why I guess your memory overflows. If you want to just int you must change your function parameters to  `bool findNumberIn2DArray(int** matrix, int matrixSize, int matrixColSize, int target)` and in 5. line you can write without an asterisk.